# Parámetro de tipo de Date en constructor

Tags: java, date, constructor, parametros

Dado un objeto con atributo de tipo Date, por ejemplo:

public class Cliente {

```
String nombre;
Date FechaDeAlta = new Date();

public Cliente(String nombre,Date f) {
    nombre=n;
    FechaDeAlta=f;
}
```

}

Se puede pasar directamente un Date directamente como parámetro en  el constructor como pongo aquí abajo o se requiere un "parseo" a String?

Cliente c1 = new Cliente("PEPE","15/10/2021");

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola no se puede "15/10/2021" es un string no un DATE

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta al crear el constructor con parámetros, es que en él le dices el tipo de dato que le vas a pasar. En este caso lo construyes con un tipo string y otro Date, por lo que es necesario que cuando crees un objeto tengas que asignarle esos tipos de datos. Tú le estás pasando un dato string a Cliente.

Por lo que en la creación de tu objeto c1 debes tener en cuenta la posición y el tipo

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("nombreString", fechaTypeDate);
```

Es como si creas un constructor así:

```
public Cliente(String nombre, int edad) {
    this.nombre=n;
    this.edad=f;
}
```

Y luego genera un objeto con ese contructor de esta manera:

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("nombreString", "25");
```

El constructor está esperando un entero, no una cadena de texto. Prueba a poner una fecha con tipo Date(). Un saludo

Comment: Tengo claro que tienen que coincidir los tipos, lo que estoy tratando de averiguar es cómo se pasa el Date.

Comment: Hola, eso depende de qué fecha quieras poner, prueba con generar nuevo Date. Date test = new Date(2021,10,15) ahí te genera un objeto de tipo date con el día, mes y año que quieres en el ejemplo. Ya que date tiene distintos constructores para generar el objeto Date. Prueba a poner un new Date en el argumento. Puedes también crear un objeto de la clase Date como he puesto arriba o llamar al método format () de la clase DateFormat y paser el objeto de fecha como parámetro en el método.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente he optado por pasar como parámetro un String como fecha en el constructor y luego parsear en los Get/Set, no veo otra forma por ahora de pasar un valor de tipo Date:

```
public void setFechaDeAlta(String f){
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        FechaDeAlta = sdf.parse(f);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Date getFechaDeAlta() {
    return FechaDeAlta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, en un constructor puedes llamar variables de cualquier tipo, incluso de otras clases.

Tu constructor y tu clase están bien, pero cuando quieres llamar a este constructor, tienes que asegurarte de enviar como segundo parámetro una variable de tipo Date. En tu ejemplo estás pasando una variable de tipo String, por lo que son incompatibles, y no se hace la conversion automatica en el proceso.

es decir que en vez de pasar esto

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("PEPE","15/10/2021");
```

tienes que transformar de antemano a Date. osea algo asi

```
Date fecha = new Date("15/10/21");
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("PEPE",fecha);
```

O como a mi me gusta acortarlo, tambien puedes hacer esto

```
Cliente c1 = new Cliente("PEPE",new Date("15/10/21"));
```

Saludos amigo!